# SQL, Select by geoposition on an area

Tags: sql, geolocation, geopoints

I'm trying to make a query that select users located on an area. 
I've this table:

`Users` (`user_id`, `username`, `user_latitude`, `user_longitude`)

I have an area defined by 2 points:

- North West (lat, lng)
- South East (lat, lng)

How to get the users with a geoposition contained on the area?

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you write the condition in plain English (not SQL) when a user should be deemed belonging to the area? Hint: user's longitude and latitude should each be in some interval.

Comment: I guess the query would be something like this: user.lat <= NorthWest.lat && user.lng >= NorthWest.lng && user.lat >= SouthEast.lat && user.lng <= SouthEast.lng,  Wouldn't it?

Comment: Instead of pasting it into the comment add it to your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive but simple approach could look like this, assuming your area is similar to a rectangle:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (user_latitude >= 1.2393 AND user_latitude <= 1.5532) 
AND (user_longitude >= -1.8184 AND user_longitude <= -1.654)
```

For more sophisticated demands, you should use geospatial functions.

Comment: Or for more intuitive form we can use `BETWEEN`

Comment: Right you are, that's indeed more intuitive.